# How can I add satellite map in OpenLayers 5?

Tags: openlayers

I have taken a look at [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/bing-maps.html) but it requires a license from Bing maps. Is there another option to show satellite view as base layer?

```
var baseLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All data sources will have terms of use (such as displaying attributions).  If you want one without an API key try

```
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    attributions: ['Powered by Esri',
                   'Source: Esri, DigitalGlobe, GeoEye, Earthstar Geographics, CNES/Airbus DS, USDA, USGS, AeroGRID, IGN, and the GIS User Community'],
    attributionsCollapsible: false,
    url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    maxZoom: 23
  })
```

Comment: Is it still the best map to find?

Comment: There are many options for satellite maps, but most need an API key.

Comment: After a little of search I can confirm that I could find better, even some paid API have the same quality...